# R - Storm integration error

Tags: r, maven, apache-storm

storm version 0.9.2 incubating
when i integrate R bolt in storm topology giving this error

ERROR backtype.storm.util - Async loop died!
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: backtype.storm.multilang.NoOutputException: Pipe to subprocess seems to be broken! No output read.
Serializer Exception:

```
at backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchToCursor(DisruptorQueue.java:128) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
at backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchWhenAvailable(DisruptorQueue.java:99) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
at backtype.storm.disruptor$consume_batch_when_available.invoke(disruptor.clj:80) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__3352$fn__3364$fn__3411.invoke(executor.clj:746) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__452.invoke(util.clj:431) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.7.0_55]
```

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: backtype.storm.multilang.NoOutputException: Pipe to subprocess seems to be broken! No output read.
Serializer Exception:

```
at backtype.storm.task.ShellBolt.execute(ShellBolt.java:157) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__3352$tuple_action_fn__3354.invoke(executor.clj:631) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$mk_task_receiver$fn__3275.invoke(executor.clj:399) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
at backtype.storm.disruptor$clojure_handler$reify__1437.onEvent(disruptor.clj:58) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
at backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchToCursor(DisruptorQueue.java:120) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
... 6 common frames omitted
```

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: backtype.storm.multilang.NoOutputException: Pipe to subprocess seems to be broken! No output read.
Serializer Exception:

```
at backtype.storm.utils.ShellProcess.readShellMsg(ShellProcess.java:99) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
at backtype.storm.task.ShellBolt$1.run(ShellBolt.java:107) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
... 1 common frames omitted
```

14865 [Thread-8-permutebolt] ERROR backtype.storm.daemon.executor - 
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: backtype.storm.multilang.NoOutputException: Pipe to subprocess seems to be broken! No output read.
Serializer Exception:

```
at backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchToCursor(DisruptorQueue.java:128) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
at backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchWhenAvailable(DisruptorQueue.java:99) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
at backtype.storm.disruptor$consume_batch_when_available.invoke(disruptor.clj:80) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__3352$fn__3364$fn__3411.invoke(executor.clj:746) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__452.invoke(util.clj:431) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.7.0_55]
```

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: backtype.storm.multilang.NoOutputException: Pipe to subprocess seems to be broken! No output read.
Serializer Exception:

```
at backtype.storm.task.ShellBolt.execute(ShellBolt.java:157) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__3352$tuple_action_fn__3354.invoke(executor.clj:631) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$mk_task_receiver$fn__3275.invoke(executor.clj:399) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
at backtype.storm.disruptor$clojure_handler$reify__1437.onEvent(disruptor.clj:58) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
at backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchToCursor(DisruptorQueue.java:120) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
... 6 common frames omitted
```

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: backtype.storm.multilang.NoOutputException: Pipe to subprocess seems to be broken! No output read.
Serializer Exception:

```
at backtype.storm.utils.ShellProcess.readShellMsg(ShellProcess.java:99) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
at backtype.storm.task.ShellBolt$1.run(ShellBolt.java:107) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
... 1 common frames omitted
```

downloaded this project from github

https://github.com/allenday/R-Storm

i went to java/stoRm directory,(R installed with packages permute and Storm)
executed mvn test....but showing the error mentioned above.